# removing account with 2 emails

Tags: sync, google-account

my primary email address in my google account was not gmail.
I used this google account in my android device for a while.
Then, I started using Gmail and it became my primary address (my former email address is still in the account, but its not anymore the primary email in it anymore).
I want to remove my former email address from the account & sync, but it says: "Removing this account will delete all of its messages, contacts, and other data from the phone!".

will my personal messaging and contacts be deleted? or it means they will just be deleted from the cloud? after all, its the same google account with different emails (the primary and my former). what will happen to the apps? are they going to be deleted too?

hope I was clear enough...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The first account you enter when you set up your phone can not be removed without resetting the whole phone.

If you do this you won't lose any cloud data but all locally installed apps and their data, eg. not your emails (cloud data) but for example sent/received SMSes (and all other locally stored data).